# Passing the '&' symbol in a flashvar

Tags: flash, flashvars

We are struggling passing the '&' symbol to a swf through the flashvars.

Here's the scenario: we have a swf file that displays some text, the data comes from a web service in .net, and we don't have the code source of the swf file.
The text that needs to be displayed, in some cases, contains the symbol &. The problem with that symbol is that it's the separator for the parameters of the flashvar.
So, for example, if I need to display 'Dogs&Cats', the swf will only read 'Dogs' (and display 'Dogs'), thinking that 'Cats' is some other parameter of the flashvar.

Would any one know some way to tell the swf that this & symbol is not a separator but it's part of a parameter?

Thanks a lot :)
Regards,
BS_C3

Answer (score 0):

& may need to be url encoded as `&amp;`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer :) However, &amp is not working... it then considers that amp is another parameter -_-'

Comment: @BS_C3: Sorry, I gave you the escaped HTML version of the '&' ampersand value. In order to provide the '&' as part of the actual param value you must replace '&' with the url escaped version '%26'.

Here's some other characters that you should ensure you encode:
$  %24
&  %26
+  %2B
,  %2C
/  %2F
:  %3A
;  %3B
=  %3D
?  %3F
@  %40

Comment: Well... actually it won't work >.< It'll be fine to encode the character so that the flashvar won't consider the second part of the text as a new parameter, but the swf file won't be able to read it properly (it'll read %26 instead of &) ... but thanks! :)